# f is differentiable with conditions. Show that f has a subsequence converging to a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable. Assume that $|f(x)| \leq 1, |f'(x)| \leq 1 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ and that $f(0) = 0$. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. Prove that the sequence of functions $g_n(x) = \frac{1}{a_n} f(a_n x)$ has a subsequence converging to a continuous function.

I know that the subsequence exists because we have a bounded function. However, we are given a specific subsequence here. How do I show this is a subsequence that converges? Is there a good way to approach this? Or maybe showing that $g_n(x)$ is equicontinuous and then using Arzela-Ascoli? Any tips to do this one would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g_n(x)=\frac 1  {a_n}\int_0^{a_nx} f'(t)dt=\int_0^{x}f'(a_ns) ds$. This gives $|g_n(x)-g_n(y)| \leq |x-y|$ and Arzela -Ascoli Theorem gives the answer.

Comment: Hi there. I like this solution, it seems really simple. However, I am not following it. What do those integrals have to do with the result you concluded? I see how the conclusion implies Arzela-Ascoli, however, I am not sure how you get to that from the integrals.

Comment: @DominicBlanco $|g(x)-g(y)|=|\int_x^{y} f'(a_n s)ds| \leq \int_x^{y} 1ds=|x-y|$.

Comment: I think I see. I see what is happening with the integral. I think you missed a part where you removed the absolute value (because by FTOC that integral is technically y - x without absolute value), but I easily see how to fix that. It makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases.  The first is that there is a subsequence of $a_n$ that converges to a non-zero number.  The second is that there is a subsequence that converges to $-\infty$ or $\infty$.  The third is that there is a subsequence that converges to 0.

In each of the three cases, prove that the corresponding subsequence of functions converges to a continuous function.  (The three cases do have to be handled differently from each other.)

---

Here is the trick for the third.  By the definition of the derivative and the fact that $f(0) = 0$,

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = f'(0)$

Which means for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |h| < \delta$ then $|\frac{f(h)}{h} - f'(0)| < \epsilon$.

Now let non-zero $x$ be fixed, $h = ax$ and suppose that there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges to 0.  Then $\frac{f(ax)}{a} = \frac{f(ax)}{ax}x$.

And now for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can pick $\delta > 0$ such that if $|ax| < \delta$ then $|\frac{f(ax)}{ax} - f'(0)| < |\frac{\epsilon}{x}$ so that $|\frac{f(ax)}{a} - f'(0)x| < \epsilon$.  But since $a_{n_k}$ converges to $0$, for all sufficiently large $k$, $|a_{n_k}| < \delta$.  This lets us prove, directly from the definitions, that the subsequence converges pointwise to $f'(0) x$.

Note that this is actually a stronger result than you were asked for.  I only need $f$ bounded, continuous, and that $f'(0)$ is well-defined.

Comment: Hi there. So if $a_n$ converges to a non-zero number, (let's say 2 for an example), then I'd have as n-> infinity g(x) = 1/2 f(2x). The f(2x) has to be less than 1 since the function was bounded. So this would go to a number. If it goes to an infinity, well, f(infinity x) I am assuming will still be bounded by 1. And the 1/infinity = 0, so g(x) = 0. If $a_n$ goes to 0, I am not quite sure as we'd have 1/0 f(0) = 1/0 * 0. I don't think I can just cancel the 0's there. It seems odd.

Comment: @DominicBlanco In the first case, you converge to a function, not a number.  In the third case, you'll have to go to the definition of the derivative to show that you converge to g(x) = f'(0) x.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I don't see the function it converges to at the moment. And I use the definition of the derivative with an $a_n$? how will that get rid of the sequence? I take the limit as h -> 0 in the definition, so I'd still have the sequence there, no convergence.

Comment: @DominicBlanco The only thing that you need to know about the subsequence is that it converges to 0.  So for any $x$, $g(x)$ will be the limit as $a$ goes to 0 of $\frac{f(ax)}{a} = \frac{f(ax)}{ax} x$.  Now you just need to prove that the fraction converges to `f'(0)`.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still not seeing how to do that from your replies. Even though this was given before we did integrals in the class, I am going to go with the other answer. I am able to follow it and it makes sense. I'm still confused with this. If you'd like to type it up that would be great, but I am still confused at this time.

Comment: @DominicBlanco I added an outline of the reasoning for the third case.  And noted that it actually proves a much stronger result than you were asked for - I think that the other approach is what the professor was looking for.